# Getting color information from an image

Tags: php, object-oriented, css, file, image

I am working on a site that themes itself based on images / logos. I have made a utility class that gets the colors from an image, shown below. I am fairly new to OOP with PHP, and I'm looking for feedback on what I could improve with the following. It is still in beta, so image-handling is a little sketchy and could use some work.

**Image Used:**

[image]

**Class:**

```
class Image {
    private $_hex = array();
    private $_size = array();
    private $_topThree = array();
    private $_im, $_mostCommon, $_minDem, $_tempHex, $_uniqueHex;
    
    public function __construct($image) {
        $ext = explode('.',$image);
        $ext = end($ext);
        if ($ext === 'png') {
            $this->_im = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        } elseif ($ext === 'jpg' || $ext === 'jpeg') {
            $this->_im = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        } else {
            die('The supplied extension is not supported. Supported formats include: jpg, jpeg, and png.');
        }
        $this->_size = getimagesize($image);
        $this->setHex();
    }
    
    public function showAll() {
        foreach($this->_uniqueHex as $k) {
            echo '<div style="background-color:'.$k.'; width:100%; height:30px;">'.$k.'</div>';
        }
    }
    
    public function getMostCommon() {
        $this->mostCommon($this->_hex);
        return $this->_mostCommon;
    }
    
    public function getTop() {
        $this->_tempHex = $this->_hex;
        $counted = array_count_values($this->_tempHex);
        arsort($counted);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($counted as $k => $v) {
            if ($i < 3) {
                $this->_topThree[$i] = $k;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $this->_topThree;
    }
    
    public function showTop() {
        if (empty($this->_topThree)) {
            $this->getTop();
        }
        foreach($this->_topThree as $k) {
            echo '<div style="background-color:'.$k.'; width:100%; height:30px;">'.strtoupper($k).'</div>';
        }
    }
    
    #########################
    ### PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ###
    #########################
    private function setHex() {
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        $this->_minDem = min($this->_size[0], $this->_size[1]);
        // Get RGB pixel by pixel
        while ($x < $this->_minDem) {
            $colors = imagecolorat($this->_im, $x, $y);
            $r = ($colors >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($colors >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $colors & 0xFF;
            // Convert RGB to Hex
            $this->_hex[] = $this->toHex($r, $g, $b);
            $x++;
            $y++;
        }
        $this->removeWhiteBlack($this->_hex);
        $this->_uniqueHex = array_unique($this->_hex);
    }
    
    private function removeWhiteBlack($array) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($array as $k) {
            $k = strtolower($k);
            if ($k === '#ffffff' || $k === '#000000') {
                unset($this->_hex[$i]);
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    
    private function mostCommon() { 
        $counted = array_count_values($this->_hex); 
        arsort($counted); 
        $this->_mostCommon = key($counted);   
    }
    
    private function toHex($r, $g=-1, $b=-1) {
        (is_array($r) && sizeof($r) == 3) ? list($r, $g, $b) = $r : NULL;
        $r = intval($r); $g = intval($g);
        $b = intval($b);
        $r = dechex($r<0?0:($r>255?255:$r));
        $g = dechex($g<0?0:($g>255?255:$g));
        $b = dechex($b<0?0:($b>255?255:$b));
        $color = (strlen($r) < 2?'0':'').$r;
        $color .= (strlen($g) < 2?'0':'').$g;
        $color .= (strlen($b) < 2?'0':'').$b;
        return '#'.$color;
    }
}
```

---

### Usage:

```
$image = new Image('FGC.png');
$topThree = $image->getTop();
$image->showTop();
echo $image->getMostCommon();
echo '<pre>', print_r($topThree, true), '</pre>';
$image->showAll();
```

---

### Output:

**Top 3:**

```
<div style="background-color:#155184; width:100%; height:30px;">#155184</div>
<div style="background-color:#009467; width:100%; height:30px;">#009467</div>
<div style="background-color:#dceae3; width:100%; height:30px;">#DCEAE3</div>
```

**Most Common Color:**

```
#155184
```

**Top Three in array:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => #155184
    [1] => #009467
    [2] => #dceae3
)
```

**Unique:**

```
<div style="background-color:#155184; width:100%; height:30px;">#155184</div>
<div style="background-color:#61749d; width:100%; height:30px;">#61749d</div>
<div style="background-color:#fffffd; width:100%; height:30px;">#fffffd</div>
<div style="background-color:#ede2d1; width:100%; height:30px;">#ede2d1</div>
<div style="background-color:#e7d6bd; width:100%; height:30px;">#e7d6bd</div>
<div style="background-color:#e2cdad; width:100%; height:30px;">#e2cdad</div>
<div style="background-color:#948e96; width:100%; height:30px;">#948e96</div>
<div style="background-color:#babfd3; width:100%; height:30px;">#babfd3</div>
<div style="background-color:#009467; width:100%; height:30px;">#009467</div>
<div style="background-color:#9b8d87; width:100%; height:30px;">#9b8d87</div>
<div style="background-color:#3da686; width:100%; height:30px;">#3da686</div>
<div style="background-color:#6d9974; width:100%; height:30px;">#6d9974</div>
<div style="background-color:#c0aa92; width:100%; height:30px;">#c0aa92</div>
<div style="background-color:#dceae3; width:100%; height:30px;">#dceae3</div>
<div style="background-color:#19986c; width:100%; height:30px;">#19986c</div>
<div style="background-color:#858880; width:100%; height:30px;">#858880</div>
<div style="background-color:#90947c; width:100%; height:30px;">#90947c</div>
<div style="background-color:#707782; width:100%; height:30px;">#707782</div>
```

Comment: See http://99designs.com/tech-blog/blog/2012/05/11/color-analysis/ and https://github.com/99designs/colorific

Comment: @DaveJarvis that's a pretty cool article

Comment: What if "most common" is a tie?  What if there is a tie for 3rd most common? Are you happy to arbitrarily lose otherwise qualifying colors? Do you ever want to present the counts for each color to see weighting?  I personally do not support declaration inside of ternaries or in other words, ternaries that do not begin with a variable declaration.

Comment: @mickmackusa this is all code I wrote when I first started as a developer 8+ years ago. I'd likely do it very differently now if I still wrote PHP.

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this is getting activity 8 years later. I was going to delete but I like Sam's answer so I'll give them the points :)

Comment: NVM, I see the tweet, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General Feedback

The class looks okay. I like how the method names follow [PSR-12 recommendation](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#44-methods-and-functions) of method names in camelCase, however it is also recommended that an underscore not be used to indicate private properties<sup>[1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#43-properties-and-constants)</sup>

> Property names MUST NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility. That is, an underscore prefix explicitly has no meaning.

The naming of some methods could be better - e.g. instead of `getTop()` a better name might be `getTopThreeUsedColors` - `getTop()` sounds like a method called to get something related to the top of the image. Maybe a better name for the class would be something like `ImageColorAnalyzer`.

[PSR-5](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md) is in draft status currently but is commonly followed amongst PHP developers. It recommends adding docblocks above structural elements like classes, methods, properties, etc. Many popular IDEs will index the docblocks and use them to suggest parameter names when using code that has been documented. At least do it for the public methods since outside code could reference the docblocks and provide hints for the parameters, return type, etc.

### Suspected bug

The description states that the code "*gets the colors from an image*" yet given that there is a single `while` loop in the method `Image::setHex()` which increments `$x` and `$y` at the same time it appears that it really gets the color at points along a diagonal line - like this:

[image]

To get all of the image colors it would likely need to have two loops- one to increment `$x` and one to increment `$y` independently.

### Suggestions

#### Check mime type

Instead of using the file extension to get the image type, check the MIME type using [`fileinfo_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) since a user could modify the extension, which may include a non-image files and that could lead to errors when the `imagecreatefrom*()` functions are called.

#### Getting top three colors

The method `Image::getTop()` iterates over all elements. Instead of looping, it could just take a slice of the array using [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

If a loop was needed, it could loop over the keys (using [`array_keys($counted)`](https://php.net/array_keys) to avoid the need to maintain `$i` separately

### Abstract common styles

In the loop of `Image::showAll()` each `<div>` contains three styles, the latter two being redundant. Those could be moved out to a `<style>` tag - either with a ruleset for `div` or other selector like a class name. In case performance/bandwidth is a concern this can decrease the amount of data returned by ~23%.

### Skip adding white and black instead of removing them later

Instead of calling `removeWhiteBlack()` the code could simply not add white and black to the array.

### Array syntax can be simplified

There isn't anything wrong with using `array()` but as of the time of writing, [PHP has Active support for versions 8.0 and 7.4](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), and since PHP 5.4 arrays can be declared with [short array syntax (PHP 5.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) - i.e. `[]`.

### Conversion of RGB to Hex values could be simpler

It looks like the code within `Image::toHex()` was pasted from an online source like [this one](https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamic-image-map-based-pixel-colour/). There are other techniques, many of which are shorter - e.g. using [`sprintf()`](https://php.net/sprintf). See answers to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32962624/1575353) for simpler alternatives (except [the answer by Rajarshi Das](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32962693/1575353) since that is nearly identical to the current code).